# Why does my Xamarin.iOS app always throw its null exceptions at the Application class level?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nullreferenceexception

**Problem**

If there's a null exception somewhere in my code (or a variety of exceptions), instead of being thrown where the null reference actually happened, Visual Studio pauses the code here instead:

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This is where the application breaks on exception
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

I should probably be more careful when I'm writing the code, but it makes it really difficult to debug the problem when the applicaiton isn't breaking where the null reference actually happens. Breaking here tells me nothing. Is it possible to fix this?

**Stack Trace Example**

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at AirlineChoice.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in D:\Development\Airline Choice Suite\Source Code\Development\Airline Choice Mobile\AirlineChoice\AirlineChoice.iOS\Main.cs:12 
2017-02-22 16:15:11.780 AirlineChoice.iOS[7647:100649] Unhandled managed exception:
The method or operation is not implemented. (System.NotImplementedException)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at AirlineChoice.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in D:\Development\Airline Choice Suite\Source Code\Development\Airline Choice Mobile\AirlineChoice\AirlineChoice.iOS\Main.cs:12
```

Comment: Revise the StackTrace of the exception, it should contain the call which threw it.

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace? It may give some clues as to the cause

Comment: @BytesGuy I added a sample of stack trace. It's not just null exceptions.

Comment: I'm having this same problem currently (Oct 2018), so it hasn't been resolved

Comment: Have anyone found the solution? Thanks!

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859255/debugging-xamarin-forms-ios-apps-on-visual-studio-using-a-mac-agent